# How to upload an image to Google Cloud Storage in Android App

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am attempting to use Google Cloud Storage to store images for an Android Application I'm building. I'm a beginner with cloud stuff but I've already set up an endpoint to store structured data in the google cloud datastore and I'm using app engines standard environment.

I've read conflicting things about how to go about this but I'm currently using this guide: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics#storage-upload-object-java and trying to do it in the endpoint I've already set up. I did try to use the library directly in the app however trying to run with the dependency for it caused the app to crash on startup.

The guide I'm using doesn't talk at all about setup like how to get a bucket object of a given name (I've found how to create one but I want to use my apps default bucket which already exists).

Questions:

1) Is doing it in the endpoint the best approach? I want the simplest possible solution so I don't really want to use an extra thing like firebase if I can avoid it

2) For whatever solution is the best, can you give/link me a comprehensive explanation of how to hook it up starting from the Uri I get from the FilePicker all the way to uploading it to GCS? I've found so many explanations which explain part of the process but they don't fit together.

Comment: Looks the Endpoint is the best approach, but do the following answers help you with your situation?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/TdevM/FirebaseStorageTest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/tdevm/storagetest/ui/GalleryActivity.java

Here's my test project which i created to upload images on Firebase Storage. Firebase Storage is based on Google Cloud Storage.Comment back if it helped !

Comment: I want to keep things as simple as possible so would you say Firebase is the best way to go? If I can achieve the same thing without needing firebase that would be ideal

Answer (score 1):

If google drive app is installed on the device where your app runs you can simply use intent `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT to create a file in the cloud.

Comment: I can't guarantee my users will unfortunately, but thanks for the answer :)